# hibernate hierarchy: NULL not allowed for discriminator column

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2db

I have an entity hierarchy based on hibernate strategy `SINGLE_TABLE` and I set `ddl-auto=update` in my application.yml.

When I run tests, using h2db, I get "*NULL not allowed for column* ".

This is my mapping:

```
==================
Shape      
    |--> Square
    |--> Cube
==================


@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "IS_SOLID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "-1")
public abstract class Shape{
...
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "null")
public class Square extends Shape{
...
}


 @Entity
 @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
 @DiscriminatorValue(value = "1")
 public class Cube extends Shape{
 ...
 }
```

I need to set **null** as discriminatorValue to one subclass.

When `ddl-auto=update` directive creates the shape table, it sets to `not null` the discriminator column, so I get "*NULL not allowed for column* ".

Is there a way to force the discriminator column to nullable using ddl-auto?

Comment: have you found a solution for it?

Comment: No, not by annotation. Only a workaround for my specific scenario: I wrote an "alter table" in method "before" of my junit test to remove `not null` at the descriminator column.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it using the columnDefinition property of @DiscriminatorColumn

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "IS_SOLID", discriminatorType = 
                     DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, columnDefinition = "INT(1) NULL")
```

Comment: I had already tried, it doesn't work.
Also columnDefinition = "INT(1)", it doesn't solve it.

Comment: Hmm... that is odd. Perhaps try remove discriminatorType too, this might be overwriting the column definition?

Comment: Removed, but... nothing.